# Removing Elements From JSON Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a JSON array which looks like this:

```
{
    "Times": [
        {
            "TimeStamp": "1588516643",
            "PremiumTime": "1",
            "ID": "473873947895897",
            "GuildID": "27823978489723789"
        },
        {
            "TimeStamp": "1588516643",
            "PremiumTime": "1",
            "ID": "473873947895897",
            "GuildID": "27823978489723789"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is There an easy way to remove all elements that meet a condition, I want to remove it if the TimeStamp in that element is less than or equal to a variable.

I've tried looping through the array but when i remove something from it i have to start the loop again because the object changed and doing that gives me errors.

Comment: You can perhaps use `filter` to create a new array with the filtered values?

Comment: removing items while looping can cause concurrency problems. Try to add whatever that doesn't match the criteria to a new array instead of removing those that match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative you should be aware of is to loop backwards.    The problem you are seeing is likely because when you remove an item, the index of every later item changes.    The length of the array is decremented too.

But notice that earlier items in the array are not affected.    So start at the far end of the array and work your way back towards the start.

And we don't care that the length changes because we only check the length once at the start of the loop, not every iteration.

```js
let obj = {
    "Times": [{
        "TimeStamp": "1588516642",
    },
    {
        "TimeStamp": "1588516643",
    },
    {
        "TimeStamp": "1588516644",
    }]
}

for (let i = obj.Times.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    if (obj.Times[i].TimeStamp <= 1588516643) {
        obj.Times.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

console.log(obj.Times);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do,

```
const obj = {
    "Times": [{
            "TimeStamp": "1588516642",
            "PremiumTime": "1",
            "ID": "473873947895897",
            "GuildID": "27823978489723789"
        },
        {
            "TimeStamp": "1588516643",
            "PremiumTime": "1",
            "ID": "473873947895897",
            "GuildID": "27823978489723789"
        }
    ]
}

const filterTimestamp = 1588516642;
const result = obj.Times.filter(element => element.TimeStamp > filterTimestamp);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a filter in JS

Assuming x is your JSON data and req_value is your required value of timestamp.

```
var req_value = '1588516641';
var y = x.Times.filter(function(item, index){
  return item.TimeStamp <= req_value;
})

console.log(y)
```